# Hiding Info Boxes that are in MarkerClusters in Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, cluster-analysis, infowindow, markerclusterer

Hi I have multiple markers with InfoBoxes attached to them that are open. I am trying to integrate MarkerClusters so that I can cluster areas with large groups of people. I can do this and it hides the markers that are within a cluster but it does not hide the infoBoxes associated with these boxes. I was wondering if there was anyway of doing so or anyway of checking whether a marker is within the cluster array or set to isVisible: false;

Any help on this would be great as Ive been trying to sort this out for hours

```
                cluster.push(marker);

                var friend_infobox = new InfoBox(myOptions);
                if(cluster.indexOf(marker) != -1) {
                    friend_infobox.close(map, marker);
                }else {
                    friend_infobox.open(map, marker);
                }
```